# Reloading a file using html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a textarea that can, quite obviously, be edited using keyboard entry.  I also want to be able to load a file using an html input.  I have done so, using the onchange event. (jsfiddle code linked below).

Suppose I load a file using the file loader - which works correctly in the example.
Then, I edit this file.  Realising that the changes I have made are not desired, I want to reload this file.  However, when using the html input, nothing changes since the selected file remains the same (the onchange event is not triggered).  Is there a way to reload a file using an html input.  (The only workaround I have found is to load a different file, then reload the original file ... which is not very elegant).

http://jsfiddle.net/aroberge/8PZyK/1/

```
var load_file = function() {
  $("#fileInput").show();
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $("#editor").text(reader.result);
        $("#fileInput").hide();
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);    
}); 
};

$("#load").on("click", function(evt) {
  load_file();
});
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the file around in the form, or is it only used for the text input?

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, I only need it for text input.  Note however that I could want to load a different file next time (for which the above just works), and not necessarily reload the same one - which I do need sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could clear out the fileInput value after you've read the file from it:

updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8PZyK/8/

```
var load_file = function() {
    $("#fileInput").show();
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files.length > 0) {
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            fileInput.value = "";
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $("#editor").val(reader.result);
                $("#fileInput").hide();
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);    
    }); 
};

$("#load").on("click", function(evt) {
    load_file();
});
```

Comment: I just tried this; when I load the file a second time (or any other file), the content of the textarea is not changed - that is, the new file content is not inserted.   Edit: this only occurs if I edit the textarea "by hand".

Comment: Actually, changing .text(reader.result) to .val(reader.result) with the above code seem to work.

Comment: really? In what browser? For me in Chrome I can load a text file and see it in your textarea, then edit the file, load it again and see the new content of the text file.

Comment: I could see the file.  The problem was: 1) load the file; 2. change the content of the textarea "by hand"; 3) reload the file - nothing was updated.  But changing .text() to .val() seemed to fix this. (Edit: .text() refers to my original post and the first version of this answer)

Comment: ah I see, changing the textarea, not the file contents. Ok I've updated the answer to use val too. Nice one.

Answer (score 3):

After the file input has changed, and you grab out the data, simple reset the input field like so:

```
fileInput.value = ""; // Or with jQuery, $('input[file]').val('')
```

This will trigger another change (which you'll want to ignore), but will allow the user to select the same file again and still give you a `change` event.

Comment: My understanding is that the value in question (files) is read only. Changing some other field (e.g. value) does not seem to trigger the onchange event.

Comment: The `value` of an input is the actual value. In this case the file (or name of the file). Resetting it *should* trigger the event. However, because you check for `.files` in your code, you shouldn't have a problem just putting this in there.